# Local Website Caching Application

Tags: chrome, web, macos, caching

I'm looking for an application(preferably in MacOS) which can cache(locally) a webpage(available to read only upon login). The page is not available to the public and hence couldn't be archived by sites such as Wayback Machine. I googled but failed to find any such app. Saving/Printing (to PDF) the webpage every time I visit the page is very time-consuming. Is there any app with such feature? Even a chrome extension would be fine...

Comment: I wonder if AppleScript and the Automator app can drive the Safari browser?

Answer (score 2):

See some of the tools to download a site in a previous stackexchange question [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7344/how-to-create-an-offline-copy-of-a-website) e.g. [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/faq.html#download) - which runs on both Apple & Windows

Comment: +1.  Using `wget` you can mirror, dereference links, change absolute links to same domain to relative links, etc.  *very* powerful tool.  A simple shell script called via `cron` is all you need, and the tools are all there on the Mac.  Good call!